# How to uninstall Jenkins on Windows?

Tags: windows, jenkins

A similar question was asked for Macs: [How to uninstall Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608996/3334520)

How do I do the same on Windows (specifically if I used the Jenkins Windows Installer to install Jenkins)?

My proposed uninstall plan is as follows, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way:

1. Uninstall the Jenkins Windows Service by executing *jenkins.exe uninstall* from the command line (as suggested here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service)
2. Simply delete the directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

Comment: If you installed with the installer you should have an entry within your control panel - software where you can uninstall it.

Comment: For some reason the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins" directory remains even after uninstalling Jenkins from the Control Panel. Is it okay to just delete this whole directory?

Comment: I'd start by stopping the service first. Maybe that will make sure the directory is deleted after uninstall. If not, simply delete it manually, and make sure the service is removed from Windows Services window.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see a Jenkins entry under "Add/Remove Programs" (I suppose that was the point of the question), but if you run the same MSI file again it will give you an option to uninstall Jenkins.

Answer (score 17):

To uninstall jenkins and its slave services

1.Simply go to the directory where jenkins is installed.

2.Then open up a cmd in that directory. (cmd in administrator mode is preferable)

3.jenkins.exe uninstall (this name could be different in case of slave jenkins services like jenkins-slave.exe or something similar, the application is present in the folder)

For Jenkins as services do the same thing except go to its working directory.

In the end you can safely delete the directories.

Answer (score 14):

1. Find the .msi (Windows Installer) file that you used to install Jenkins. For me, it was in a .zip file in my Downloads folder.
2. Double-click it. (You can double-click the .msi file inside the compressed folder. There's no need to extract it first.)
3. Since Jenkins is already installed, Windows Installer will give you options to customize it or remove it.
4. Choose "Uninstall."

Comment: In this way, even after a reboot, Jenkins do not do a clean install, it asks username and password instead of the autogenerated admin password. How to complete restart from scratch?

Comment: @realtebo: First uninstall, then delete the installation folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\) and finally reinstall. It should now ask you for the secret in the initialAdminPassword file.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a clean reinstall, you will need to delete some more, in addition to uninstalling and deleting the Jenkins home folder. Otherwise, they will remain there forever and will show up after reinstalling. To completely remove everything for Jenkins from Windows (I am giving this information from Windows 10, 64 bit):

1. Open Windows **Control Panel** and click `Programs and Features`
2. Right-click **Jenkins** `x.xxx.x` (where `x.xxx.x,` is the Jenkins version), and select `Uninstall`.
3. Follow the directions.
4. When done, delete the following folders: (**note:** DO NOT remove the `jenkins.jenkins` or `jenkinswar` folders if you want to keep the projects and plugins.)

   `C:\Program Files\Jenkins` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`
   `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins`
   `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkinswar`
5. Restart the computer.

Comment: this is the answer to remove completely

Answer (score 0):

Building on Rafiq's post, also navigate to `C:\ProgramData` and delete the folder that is in there. It is a hidden folder so you will need to enable hidden folders

Comment: Should be a comment rather an answer since it's part of the solution

Answer (score 0):

Go below location and delete ".jenkins" directory

C:\Users<userName>.jenkins

Note : if your not able to remove all files means process is running background , better to restart your system then delete  ".jenkins" directory