# how to delete jenkins that was installed as jenkins.war on windows?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'm using OS Windows

I'm trying to delete jenkins, that was installed as jenkins.war file. I need to delete it, because I made a lot of mistakes while configuring it.

I was trying to run the

```
jenkins.war uninstall
```

but it does not work ( in this occurance the popup window opens and suggest me to select the program which will run this command )

Also I tried to find the jenkins sevice by running the

```
service.msc
```

But there was not this service in the list.

Please help me to resolve this problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall Jenkins on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677637/how-to-uninstall-jenkins-on-windows)

Comment: @KristinaBankova i saw that answer. i was trying to do that, but it did not helped

Comment: If you made mistakes in Jenkins configurations, deleting JENKINS_HOME folder should be enough. For more info check  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins. Jenkins configuration are xml files in JENKINS_HOME folder and its subfolders.

Comment: @KristinaBankova i had a problem with user configuration, not with some generall configuration. I just tried to delete a folder, and download again jenkins.war, started it , but the result was the same  - it took me to the page on localhost with same configurations that i had

Comment: http://prntscr.com/iss870 here you can see that there is no any 'jenkins' service running :\ so i cant delete it from services

Comment: jenkins.war uninstall  also does not works

Comment: Could you please give more details about the user configuration issue and which folder did you try to delete? Which Jenkins version is the war file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run Jenkins again by `java -jar jenkins.war` from command line
you can find a line like that

```
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\martinruan\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
```

Delete the directory .jenkins then you are able reinstall Jenkins.

Comment: This is what fixed my issue. The uninstall command `$/Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command` itself does not removes this folder and as a result if you install jenkins again, you would see the same old data/users/jobs configured.