# How to uninstall Jenkins installed from jenkins.war on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, war, uninstallation

I have downloaded and installed Jenkins on an Ubuntu 14.04 operating system. Jenkins is currently running as a service.

Once Jenkins has been installed on Ubuntu 14.04 via the Jenkins.war file, how is it uninstalled?

I'm trying to do some backup testing and cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. The only directions I've been able to find are instructions to [uninstall the Jenkins package](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/j/jenkins-executable-war/uninstall/index.html). When I run any similar commands for uninstalling Jenkins packages, I receive the message:

```
Package 'jenkins' is not installed, so not removed
```

or

```
Package 'jenkins-executable-war' is not installed, so not removed
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

We need to stop jenkins first.

`sudo service jenkins stop`

Then try 
`sudo apt-get remove --purge jenkins`

If problem still exists, Try removing it manually using these instructions. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621186/3086531

Comment: This command, after stopping jenkins as a service, yields the same results as I have outlined above. Jenkins was installed via a jenkins.war file, not by package.

Answer (score 0):

for RHEL/Linux guys please stop the jenkins and then remove below folder

```
$user.home/.jenkins
```

Like if user home directory is /root then remove /root/.jenkins