# How to uninstall Jenkins MacOS

Tags: jenkins, devops

I'm using MacOS and I've downloaded Jenkins using Terminal from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/)

I've tried following different approachs to uninstall it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608996/how-to-uninstall-jenkins)

But the problem I'm facing is that I didn't download the package and it's not located at `/Application`

I've tried `brew uninstall jenkins-lts` and got the error:  `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "jenkins-lts".`

Any other ways to uninstall Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case `jenkins` was installed alongside `jenkins-lts`, try:

• `brew uninstall jenkins --force`

Then try uninstalling by looking inside `/Library` instead of `/Application`:

• `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist\n/Library/Application \ Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command`

Remove `~/.jenkins` folder & restart your system!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following:

```
brew remove jenkins-lts
```

After which the package will be removed. I needed to do this because in addition I also had jenkins installed.